# How to configure symfony2 session lifetime

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm trying to make a "remember me" check button to fix the user session for more time than the lifetime specified in the config. I'm using the symfony2 session lifetime withe the help of the `NativeSessionStorage` class.

```
$nativeSession = new NativeSessionStorage(
        array(
            'cookie_lifetime' => 3600*24*7
        )
    );
```

When i try to start the session that i've created, symfony throw this exception.

```
if($_SESSION){
        session_destroy();
        $nativeSession->start();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Anyone has the right process the declare this kind of sessions.

Comment: This is not helping too much. I don't want to change the value in the config.yml but directly in the code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The config is the way to go because in Symfony2 you're not working with the native Session class but with the Symfony2 Session class.

Comment: I'm trying to make a "remember me" check button to fix the user session for more time than the lifetime specified in the config.

Comment: Please add this information to your question, so you can read out why your question is no duplicate right out the question and not in the comments! This helps to keep the site more clean! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build a remember me functionality in Symfony2, you can define a longer lifetime for this function in the symfony2 config. See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) for additional information. Example also taken from there.

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            # ...
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
                # by default, the feature is enabled by checking a
                # checkbox in the login form (see below), uncomment the
                # following line to always enable it.
                #always_remember_me: true
```